# java mongo create date

Tags: java, mongodb, date

I have a java code that is inserting an object into a collection in Mongo DB.
While I insert this new object (details of the object given below), I need to also insert a creation date. 
What's the best way to handle this? Since we have different time zones, I want to make sure that I am following the correct approach for saving and reading the date fields.

document structure:  I need to have my java code create a system date that would insert the creation date into Mongo DB in a proper format.

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("568ac782e4b0fbb00e4f1e45"),
    "cat" : "Abc",
    "name" : "testName"
}

Please advise.

Comment: you have the [$currentDate](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) operator

Comment: Java `ObjectId` has a `getDate()` method which returns insert data

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach - use standard **Spring Data MongoDB auditing** feature (assuming, your project is Spring based).

1. Add `spring-data-mongodb` dependency
2. Annotate your main class with `@EnableMongoAuditing`
3. Add to your mongoDb entity class a field `LocalDate createdDate`
4. Annotate this new field with `@CreatedDate`
5. Profit. Every new saved entity will automatically get current date
   injected in this new field.

So, your main class will look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class SpringDataMongodbAuditingApplication {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataMongodbAuditingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And your entity class will look like this:

```
@Document    
public class Client {

        @Id
        private ObjectId id;

        private String name;

        @CreatedDate
        private LocalDate createdDate;

        // constructor, getters, setters and other methods here ...
    }
```

Your repository interface has nothing special:

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends MongoRepository<Client, ObjectId> {

}
```